# Android: Rearrange views using drag-and-drop

Tags: android, android-layout, drag-and-drop, android-animation

I'm trying to rearrange views (cards, in particular) using drag-and-drop.

My initial thought for a simple implementation is to reposition a view by removing it from the parent and then adding it to the spot on the left or on the right.

This seems to work fine without animations, but once I start using animations, sometimes cards get stuck. I get the error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field
>   'android.view.IWindowSession android.view.View$AttachInfo.mSession' on
>   a null object reference at
>   android.view.View.startDrag(View.java:18353) at
>   cz.cvut.mazelmir.cards.Cards$AFragment$2.onTouch(Anagram.java:158)

I'm not quite sure what to make of that, as the things passed to `onTouch` are the view being touched (shouldn't be null) and newly created parameters.

Any clue as to why this happening and what I could do to fix it?
Or at least some hints as to how to best implement this drag-and-drop functionality? (Perhaps a simple frame view where I just animate the cards?)

Here's the code for the fragment containing the cards: (The fragment layout is just a linear layout, and the card layout contains a textview.)

```
public static class AFragment extends Fragment {

    String s = "string";
    ViewGroup emptyContainer;
    View[] cards;
    float[] cardLoc;

    public AFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_anagram, container, false);
        emptyContainer = null;
        cards = null;
        cardLoc = null;

        createCards(inflater, linearLayout, s);

        linearLayout.setOnDragListener(new View.OnDragListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onDrag(View view, DragEvent event) {
                View draggedItem = (View) event.getLocalState();
                ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) view;
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                        if (cardLoc == null)
                            createPositions();
                        emptyContainer = viewGroup;
                        draggedItem.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        break;
                    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION:
                        int emptyPos = (int)draggedItem.getTag(R.id.position_tag);
                        float currentX = event.getX();

                        // To the right?
                        if (emptyPos < cardLoc.length - 1 && currentX > cardLoc[emptyPos + 1]) {
                            viewGroup.removeView(cards[emptyPos + 1]);
                            viewGroup.addView(cards[emptyPos + 1], emptyPos);

                            TranslateAnimation translateAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(cardLoc[emptyPos + 1] - cardLoc[emptyPos], 0, 0, 0);
                            translateAnimation.setDuration(200);
                            cards[emptyPos + 1].startAnimation(translateAnimation);

                            View tempView = cards[emptyPos + 1];
                            cards[emptyPos + 1] = cards[emptyPos];
                            cards[emptyPos] = tempView;

                            draggedItem.setTag(R.id.position_tag, emptyPos + 1);
                            tempView.setTag(R.id.position_tag, emptyPos);
                        }
                        // To the left?
                        else if (emptyPos > 0 && currentX < cardLoc[emptyPos]) {
                            viewGroup.removeView(cards[emptyPos - 1]);
                            viewGroup.addView(cards[emptyPos - 1], emptyPos);

                            TranslateAnimation translateAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(cardLoc[emptyPos - 1] - cardLoc[emptyPos], 0, 0, 0);
                            translateAnimation.setDuration(200);
                            cards[emptyPos - 1].startAnimation(translateAnimation);

                            View tempView = cards[emptyPos - 1];
                            cards[emptyPos - 1] = cards[emptyPos];
                            cards[emptyPos] = tempView;

                            draggedItem.setTag(R.id.position_tag, emptyPos - 1);
                            tempView.setTag(R.id.position_tag, emptyPos);
                        }

                        break;
                    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                        draggedItem.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

        return linearLayout;
    }

    private void createCards(LayoutInflater inflater, LinearLayout container, String s) {
        cards = new View[s.length()];
        int j = 0;
        for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
            String letter = String.valueOf(c);

            View letterCard = inflater.inflate(R.layout.letter_container, container, false);
            TextView letterTextView = (TextView) letterCard.findViewById(R.id.letter_text);
            letterTextView.setText(letter);
            letterCard.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                        ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
                        View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(v);
                        v.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, v, 0);
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
            cards[j] = letterCard;
            container.addView(letterCard);

            letterCard.setTag(R.id.position_tag, j);
            letterCard.setTag(R.id.letter_tag, letter);

            j++;
        }
    }

    public void createPositions() {
        cardLoc = new float[cards.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
            cardLoc[i] = cards[i].getX();
        }
    }
}
}
```